How to open a cam's specific in DVR with FFmpeg?
I would like to know how to direct FFmpeg to open a specific channel on the DVR. The same syntax used in VLC does not work via the Linux terminal. By entering only the username, password, IP and port, it opens channel 01.

Photo 1: Syntax ffplay rtsp://user:password@ip:port opens perfectly as shown in the photo. But I can't open the other channels.


Photo 2: The standard syntax opens perfectly in VLC (But it doesn't work in FFmpeg rtsp://admin:wesley12345@192.168.1.100:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2&subtype=1 changing Channel=x to the desired channel.



Could you help me with the syntax to direct the camera openings?

What is the model number of the DVR?

The ffplay shows ...192.168.1.100:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2 Try the full path with ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.100:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2 and just change the channel number. The & in &subtype=1 is likely messing it up. If you put ' or "'s around the URL, &subtype=1 will work.

Try adding double quotes to the
URL like this:
ffplay "rtsp://admin:wesley12345@192.168.1.100:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2&subtype=1"

That should contain special characters like ? and & to the URL and not have them inadvertently processed by the shell.
